# How to upload large mobi file to iPad/iPhone

Tags: books, kindle

I have a 63mb mobi format book.

Normally I get mobi books to my iPad/iPhone via the email share setting in Calibre. However the size of the book is too big to do that.

How else I do open up the mobi file? Any way to get iTunes to sync it to iBooks? or to use iCloud? I've got the file in Dropbox, but when I try to open the file in Kindle, it does not show up. iBooks is not given as an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can’t say how to get it into the Kindle app, but the problem with iBooks is that it’s the wrong file format.

Calibre can convert it to ePub (Convert books menu), then you can get it into iBooks in a variety of ways. (control-click to get the context menu, save to disk, then drop on iTunes/iBooks)

Comment: I was able to use DropBox, and open the ePub file with iBooks.